# Autofocus Input Element on Modal Open Bootstrap 4

Tags: input, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4, autofocus

I am trying to autofocus input element on bootstrap 4 modal open . I have tried below code from http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ but this is not working.

Can someone help me to give working demo

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
})
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the snippet below. Perhaps you need [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#myInput').trigger('focus');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myInput">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I am also use this code

```
<script>
    function setFocus(){
        $('#searchModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#q').focus();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Where **#searchModal** is modal div ID and **#q** is input element ID

Use this code in button

```
<button type="button" onclick="setFocus()">Open Modal</button>
```